# INSERT INTO TAB SELECT * FROM TABLE TAB@db2 - Too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to move rows between two tables which have many columns.

The table columns are identical other than the destination table (tab@db2) has a few more columns which causes a simple INSERT to fail.

I'd like to use a simple PL/SQL statement to build a list of the columns in tab@db2 dynamically instead of typing out the names of col1, col2, etc in the INSERT and SELECT clause. Example

```
declare a variable as var_col_list

set col_list = output of select * from tab (omitting rows)

INSERT INTO TAB *var_col_list* SELECT *var_cols_list* FROM TABLE TAB@db2
```

I've researched using %rowtype but cannot find a suitable example that would take less time than simply writing out the names of the columns!

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Basically you need to use dynamic SQL.  Construct the SQL query as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use e.g. TOAD, you can right-click the table and let it **Generate statement** - in your case, that would be **INSERT**. You'd slightly modify it (remove columns you don't need) and that's all.

---

Otherwise, this is how you might do it *semi-manually*.

This is my *source* table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON
```

*Target* table doesn't contain all columns:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE target
  2  (
  3     deptno   NUMBER,
  4     dname    VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );

Table created.
```

Code which loops through all `TARGET` table columns (i.e. a table which has *less* columns) and composes the `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (1000);
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT column_name
  5                     FROM user_tab_columns
  6                    WHERE table_name = 'TARGET')
  7     LOOP
  8        l_str := l_str || ', ' || cur_r.column_name;
  9     END LOOP;
 10
 11     l_str :=
 12        'insert into target select ' || LTRIM (l_str, ', ') || ' from dept';
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);
 14
 15     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 16  END;
 17  /
insert into target select DEPTNO, DNAME from dept          --> this is the L_STR contents
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM target;

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
        30 SALES
        40 OPERATIONS
```

Seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution provided by Littefoot, I made some minor tweaks to fit my requirement perfectly:

```
SQL> create table taba (col1 number,col2 number);
SQL> insert into taba values (1,2);
SQL> select * from taba;

       COL1       COL2
 ---------- ----------
          1          2


SQL> create table tabb (col1 number,col2 number, col3 number);

SQL> DECLARE
       l_str  VARCHAR2 (32767);
    BEGIN
       FOR cur_r IN (SELECT column_name
                       FROM user_tab_columns
                      WHERE table_name = 'TABA'
                      order by column_id asc)
       LOOP
          l_str := l_str || ', ' || cur_r.column_name;
       END LOOP;
 
      l_str :=
         'insert into tabb (' || LTRIM (l_str, ', ') || ') ' ||' select ' || LTRIM (l_str, ', ') || ' from taba';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);
 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
   END;
   /
```

Output of l_str (SQL INSERT):

```
insert into tabb (COL1, COL2)  select COL1, COL2 from taba
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from tabb;
   
      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2
```